# Extracting from multiple dictionaries to csv

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I currently have a list of dictionaries where the dictionaries contain lists sorted by a keyword like this.  The lists in each dictionary are the same length, but vary from dictionary to dictionary, and there is the same number of keywords in every dictionary.

```
dicts[file1] = {Header1:[1,2,3], Header2:[4,5,6],... etc}
dicts[file2] = {Header1:[7,8,9,0], Header2:[4,3,7,7],... etc}
...
dicts[filen] = {...}
```

I would like to extract two of the lists (say 'Header1' and 'Header5')from each dictionary and put them into a .csv file side by side with blank spaces filled in for the lists that were not as long as some others.

I am almost 100% sure that to do this I want to use izip_longest, but I am struggling with the correct format for izip_longest to accomplish this. I guess my main hangup is that I do not know what to put into the *args to properly cycle through this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: code by request.

```
writefiel = open(somefile.csv, delimiter=',')
xcolumn = 'Header1'
ycolumn = 'Header5'
for i in len(dicts):
    for lines in izip_longest(*dicts[i][xcolumn], fillvalue=['']*2):
        writefile.writerow([dicts[i][xcolumn],dicts[i][ycolumb]])
```

This just doesn't work, but I have been pounding my head off the formatting and have not been able to figure out what I am not doing right.

csv output I would like to look something like this.

```
Header1,Header5,Header1,Header5,Header1,Header5,...
1,2,4,6,3,8...
1,2,,,3,8,...
```

Answer:

First thanks everyone for giving me a hand.  This is what I ended up with.  If you see any way that would improve it I would love to hear it so I could improve my skills.

```
xhold =(list(izip_longest(*(d[xcolumn] for d in dicts), fillvalue='')))
yhold =(list(izip_longest(*(d[ycolumn] for d in dicts), fillvalue='')))

writefile.writerow([xcolumn, ycolumn, '']*len(xhold))
for i in range(len(xhold)):
    row=[]
    for j in range(len(xhold[i])):
        row=row+[xhold[i][j],yhold[i][j],'']
    writefile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what the output should look like?

Comment: I have added some code in an edit to the original post.

Comment: @deadstump: Thanks for the code. Can you also post an example of how you want your csv file to look? Your description was a little bit fuzzy.

Comment: I have added the csv output in the main body.  I am currently digesting the format fraxel provided in his or her answer below.  My main challenge is extracting the data (trying to understand how to apply izip_longest).  I am fairly comfortable putting it into csv files.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out (answer below).  Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
import itertools
itertools.izip_longest([1,2,3,4],[7,8])

lists_to_extract = ['Header1','Header2']
long_list_of_dicts = [{'Header1':[1,2,3], 'Header2':[4,5,6], 'Header3':[7,8,9]},
             {'Header1':[7,8,9,0], 'Header2':[4,3,7,7], 'Header3':[14,13,17,17]}]

print [list(itertools.izip_longest(*(d[key] for d in long_list_of_dicts),
             fillvalue=' ')) for key in lists_to_extract]
#Output:
[[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (' ', 0)], [(4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 7), (' ', 7)]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for laying out that format.  It wasn't quite what I was looking for, but it pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot to add that I added my solution to the original post.  You can really see your influence in it.  Thanks again.